# Why a loop over MySQL query change an array which has nothing to do with the query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following piece of code:

```
print_r($queries);
$id2query = array(); 
while ($res_array = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $id = $res_array['id'];
    $query = $res_array['query'];
    $id2query[$id] = $query;
}
print_r($queries);
```

The interesting thing is that `printr_r` before and after the loop return different things.

Does anybody know how it can be possible?

**ADDED**

`$queries` is an array. It shown code is a part of a function and `$queries` is one of the arguments of the function. Before the loop it returns:

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

and after the loop it returns:

```
Array ( [0] => web 2.0 )
```

**ADDED 2**

`web 2.0` comes from `$res_array`. Here is the content of the `$res_array`:

```
Array ( [0] => 17 [id] => 17 [1] => web 2.0 [query] => web 2.0 [2]
```

But I do not understand how a value from `$res_array` migrates to `$queries`.

**ADDED 3**

I tried

```
print "AAAA".var_dump($queries)."BBB";
```

it returns `AAABBB`.

**ADDED 4**

I have managed to use `var_dump` in the correct way and this is what it returns before the loop:

```
array(1) { [0]=> &string(0) "" }
```

This is what I have after the loop:

```
array(1) { [0]=> &string(7) "web 2.0" }
```

But I do not understand what it means.

Comment: What is the variable `$queries`? How is it created and what does it contain?

Comment: What does print_r($queries); output before and after the loop?

Comment: Maybe `$queries` is a [reference](http://php.net/language.references) to another variable (like `$id2query`). Try `var_dump` to get more information about the variable. If it’s a reference, you will get something like `&array …`.

Comment: I think that for all the readers it qould be useful to tell us how `$queries` is inisialised along with `$results` - Then we get the full picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var_dump below **ADDED 4** shows it, the array contains a reference to a string. So it is not a copy of that string, it is something like a pointer (I know, they are not real pointers, see PHPDocs below) to the original string. So if that one gets changed, the references shows the changed value too.

I'd suggest you have a look at:
[PHPDoc References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php)
[PHPDoc What references do](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

Example code:

```
$s = "lulu";
$a = array(&$s);
var_dump($a);
$s = "lala";
var_dump($a);
```

First var_dump will return:

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>
 &string(4) "lulu"
}
```

And the second:

```
array(1) {
 [0]=>
 &string(4) "lala"
}
```